# how to get the data from subscriber

Tags: ros, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In python I have this:

self.cmd_vel_sub = rospy.Subscriber('cmd_vel', Twist, self.cmd_vel)

and I need to access the angular velocity of this subscriber. How can I do it?

I've tried:

self.cmd_vel_sub[1][2]

self.cmd_vel_sub.angle.z

But non work.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12115/how-to-get-the-data-from-subscriber/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2011-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Go through the basic tutorials http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials especially 11.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4